# How to recheck ruby condition on client-side event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, client-side, soundcloud

I have a SoundCloud widget that is set to hide if a playlist is empty. Is there a method to recheck the condition when someone adds a song to the playlist (clicks add button)?

```
  <% if @current_user.id == Integer(@party_profile.host) %>
    <div <% if @firstsong == "undefined" %> style="display:none;" <% end %>>
      <object height="81" width="80%" id="myPlayer" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
        <iframe id="sc-widget" width="95%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/<%= @firstsong %>&show_artwork=true&liking=ture&sharing=true&frameborder="no"&scrolling="no"&enable_api=true&object_id=myPlayer"></iframe>
      </object>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

The reason I've added this ruby condition instead of refreshing a partial of the soundcloud widget onclick is because I don't want the widget to refresh every time someone adds a song (only if the player was hidden and new song has been added).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, once the server hands it off to the client, all the erb content is set in stone. What you can do however is write a js function to handle the client side event

$().ready(function() {
    $("#some_id_of_a_dom_element_that_changes_due_to_a_user_addition").change(function() {
      $("song_container").show()
    })
  })

Comment: Any suggestions on how to use a js function that only causes the widget to refresh if it was hidden before?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here:

1. (Good news) There's a <strike>new</strike> [HTML5-based widget](http://blog.soundcloud.com/2012/01/26/html5-widget/) which also looks way better than the flash one (and works on iOS, etc).
2. (Good news) The widget has an [API](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget).
3. (Bad news) Getting real-time updates on the content of a playlist isn't what the SoundCloud API, nor the Widget is designed for. There is some level of caching for performance reasons which means that what the widget gets may be some amount of time behind reality.

It's hard to say what would be the best solution for you without knowing what your intended use is.